# Android XML layout preview not working in Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 Patch 1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-layout-editor

Can anyone help how to resolve the preview issue for XML layout file?

[image][image]

Comment: Are you not able to open any xml or only 1 specific. if its only single xml then check if there are any errors in the xml file.

Comment: Facing issues in all the XML. Earlier it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the .idea folder and restart Invalidate caches / Restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Solution # 1

If you are using any Custom-View/Component-View, you must need to set a theme to that view.

Solution # 2

You need to fix these xml errors (maybe `alt + enter` help to fix them)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error in version. `Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1`

I did the following steps and only one worked for me:

- Invalidate Caches ❌
- Clean Project ❌
- Rebuild Project ❌
- Remove `build` Folder ❌
- Remove `.idea` Folder ✅

[image]

Make sure you're using the Android Studio with the latest version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to **Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1**. fix the problem.

[image]
as you can see here https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/fixed-bugs/studio/2022.2.1

(from my experience, this issue occurred on Dolphin and Electric Eel. Before that, Chipmunk was fine)